# forecolor of "dirty" cells in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0, datagridview

I'm working on a Winforms application that contains a `DataGridView`, which is bound to a `DataTable`.

The user is allowed to edit content of the cells. User's "dirty" input should appear in blue forecolor until it's saved to the database (cell forecolor is then reset to the default forecolor, black).

When the user edits a cell, I set the cell forecolor to blue in the `CellValueChanged` event handler. But after the user clicks the Save button (which calls `Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.MyDataSet)`), the modified cells are still blue.

How can I reset the forecolor of the blue cells? Loop over all cells? (Sounds inefficient to me.) Refresh the DGV? (`DGV.Refresh()` seems to not work.)

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) to store row/column of the modified cells.

When user clicks the save button:

- restore the default color of the listed cells
- clear List